# geometry's includehead doesn't work properly with multiline header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, geometry

I am programming a class (based on koma-script article) which includes a changing header, so sometimes a multiline header is possible. With this setting I cannot fix the top distance of 2cm.

The following MWE shows the unwanted effect, where `top=2cm` and `includehead` are set, but the multiline header reaches the page's top margin closer.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\lohead{line 1\\line 2\\line 3\\line 4}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, includehead, headsep=.5cm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
   ...
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

I know the possibility to set the `headheight` option manually, but I want an auto changing header height whose top is always 2cm distant to the page's margin. How could I achive that?

Comment: How could an »auto changing header« have a top, which always has a distance of 2 cm? The »auto change« would make it thinner or broader?

Comment: My intention is that the header's top margin has always a distance of 2cm from the page's top margin. So if the header is bigger, the the text body should shift downwards. This is what I understand by typing `top=2cm, includehead`.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a bug: `includehead` has no effect.

Comment: Are there any workarounds known?

Comment: I've no idea, but what about a bug report to koma-script?